# Header bar not display list view in Sencha 2.x

Tags: listview, sencha-touch-2, dataview

I have list items in a tabpanel. Header bar not displaying in the Browse list page. If any one have the solution please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Main.js

`Ext.define('myapp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'myapp.view.Browse'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'browseView',
                title: 'Blog',
                iconCls: 'star'
            }
        ]
    }
});`

Browse.js

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Browse', {    extend: "Ext.Container",
xtype: "browseView",
id: 'browseView',
requires: ["Ext.dataview.List", "myapp.view.Header"],
config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'fit' //set containers layout
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: "headerview"
    }, {
        store: "Browse",
        xtype: 'list', //add xtype
        onItemDisclosure: false,
        itemTpl: [
            '<img src="{Image_path}" width="80" height="90" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" /><h4 style="color:blue;">{Name}</h4><p>{Description}</p><div style="clear: both"></div>'
        ]
    }]
} });
```

Header.js

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Header', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: "headerview",
config: {
    height: '60',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    defaults: {
        flex: '1'
    },
    style: 'text-align:left;width: 100%',
    items: [{
        html: '<div class="header_bg"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"/></div>'
    }]
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

1) For 2 items, you should use hbox / vbox, fit is meant for single item and that single takes full size of the screen.

2) Give height for the two items within browseView.

***So your browseView code***

```
Ext.define('Rest.view.Browse',{  
extend: "Ext.Container",
xtype: "browseView",
id: 'browseView',
requires: ["Ext.dataview.List", "Rest.view.Header"],
config: {
    items: [{
        xtype: "headerview",
        height : '40%'
    }, {
        store: "Browse",
        height : '60%',
        xtype: 'list', //add xtype
        onItemDisclosure: false,
        itemTpl: [
            '<img src="{Image_path}" width="80" height="90" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" /><h4 style="color:blue;">{Name}</h4><p>{Description}</p><div style="clear: both"></div>'
        ]
    }]
} 
});
```